# Trenne nie st – warum?

Tags: spelling, blackletter

In der alten Rechtschreibung bildete die Buchstabenkombination *st* eine Ausnahme bei der Silbentrennung, da sie nicht getrennt wurde, auch wenn es im Widerspruch zu den sonstigen Trennregeln stand. Man trennte z. B. *Knos-pen*, *Kon-ten*, *hor-ten*, aber *ko-sten*. Einzige Ausnahme waren Wortfugen (Diens-tag).

Die entsprechende Regel für gebrochene Schriften war schlicht »Trenne nie *ſt*« (da *st* immer und nur an Wortfugen auftrat).

Als Begründung für diese Regel wird meistens in etwa Folgendes genannt: *ſt* bildete im Fraktursatz eine sogenannte Zwangsligatur, die z. B. auch beim Sperren der Buchstaben zusammenblieb und teilweise wie ein eigener Buchstabe behandelt wurde (wie z. B. auch das *ß*, dessen Ursprünge auch in einer Ligatur liegen). Das ist zwar so weit richtig, aber nun gehörte neben *ſt*, *ch* und *ck* eben auch *tz* zu den Zwangsligaturen, und dieses wurde getrennt (z. B. Kat-ze) – und das obwohl es sowohl aussprachetechnisch als auch typografisch viel eher Eigenschaften eines Buchstabens aufwies. Das alleine konnte es also nicht gewesen sein. (Analog, nur etwas komplizierter auch für *ck.*)

Gibt es irgendeine Erklärung dafür, warum *ſt* nicht getrennt wurde, *tz* aber schon?

Comment: Ich hätte den Superlativ im Verdacht (schöns-te), aber man müßte wohl in die Unterlagen der II. Orthographischen Konferenz schauen.

Comment: Ich hatte eine wunderschöne Theorie, die auf den Unterschied zwischen *Haus-teil* und *hauſ-te* hinarbeitete, war dabei sie auszuformulieren, als mir aufgefallen ist, dass *ſſ* ja auch *ſ- ſ* getrennt wurde. Das schließt ästhetische Argumente (*ſ-* sei hässlich) aus, und erschafft gleichzeitig einen Präzedenzfall einer Ligaturtrennung. Bliebe höchstens noch, dass ſt so oft vorkäme. Was auch nicht per se überzeugt.

Comment: @Jan: *ſ-* hattest Du nebenbei auch bei Wörtern wie *Weſ-pe* und *laſ-ziv.* Die Ligaturtrennung bei *ſſ* ist weniger spektakulär als die von *ſt,* da *ſſ* keine Zwangsligatur war, also bei Sperrung nicht beibehalten wurde. Viel wichtiger ist hier die Zwangsligatur *tz*, die nicht gesperrt, aber sehr wohl getrennt wurde, z. B. in *Kat-ze.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Naja, Henne oder Ei. Wurde *ſt* nicht getrennt, weil es eine Zwangsligatur war, oder wurde *ſt* zu einer Zwangsligatur, weil es nicht getrennt wurde? Vielleicht ist auch die wahre Frage *warum wurde* tz *überhaupt getrennt?* Denn schließlich ist die *tz*-Ligatur dem unzertrennlichen *ß* viel näher als *ſt* es je werden könnte (in dem Sinne, dass die Form des z stark verändert wurde).

Comment: Warum? »denn es tut den beiden weh«. Diesen Spruch habe ich jedenfalls in der Schule gelernt: »Trenne nie S-T, denn es tut den beiden weh.«

Comment: Eine hypothetische Regel, die _ſt / ʃt (ﬅ)_ und _ſs / ſz / ſʒ / ʃs / ʃz / ʃʒ (ß)_ aber nicht _ch, ck, tz / tʒ (ꜩ)_ und auch nicht _st (ﬆ), ss, sz / sʒ_ abdeckt, wäre: „Trenne keine Oberlängenligaturen!“. Allerdings durften _ft, ff (ﬀ), fl (ﬂ), tt_ durchaus getrennt werden – markanterweise mit ggf. durchgezogenem Querstrich –, also eher: „Trenne keine Ligaturen, die mit _ſ_ beginnen!“, denn bspw. „Trenne keine Ligaturen, die sich über alle Bänder erstrecken (können)“ kann auch auf _f (ƒ)_ zutreffen.

Comment: @Crissov: Die Hypothese scheitert an *ſſ* (z. B. in *Waſ-ſer), ſl* (z. B. in *wechſ-le)* oder *ſb* (in *Aſ-beſt).* Siehe auch [Jans Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/trenne-nie-st-warum?noredirect=1#comment50294_7928) weiter oben.

Comment: War denn _ſſ_ eine Zwangsligatur? _ſl, ſb_ oder auch _ſk_ und _ſh_ dürften in deutschen Druckereien eher selten als Ligatur vorhanden gewesen sein.  _ck_ und _tz_ unterscheiden sich auch dadurch von _ſt_, dass sie Ersatzschreibungen für die Doppelbuchstaben _kk_ und _zz_ sind, die behandelt werden sollten wie bspw. _ſſ_ – dann wäre die Frage eher, warum neben _Kak-ke_ nicht auch _Kaz-ze_ getrennt wurde und die Antwort wäre vielleicht, dass außer an Morphemgrenzen _z_ nach Vokal immer ein _t_ erfordert, also wäre höchstens _Katz-ze_ möglich.

Comment: *War denn* ſſ *eine Zwangsligatur?* – Nein, aber die *f*-Ligaturen waren es auch nicht. Wenn Du dies mit einbeziehen möchtest, kannst Du auch Regeln wie »Trenne keine Oberlängenzwangsligaturen.« oder »Trenne keine Zwangsligaturen, die mit *ſ* beginnen« ersinnen, die aber wenig aussagekräftig sind, da es eben nur vier bzw. fünf Zwangsligaturen gab (je nachdem, ob man *ß* hinzuzählt). — ſl, ſb *oder auch* ſk *und* ſh *dürften in deutschen Druckereien eher selten als Ligatur vorhanden gewesen sein.* – *ſt* war in vielen Schriften auch keine tatsächliche Ligatur, wurde aber dennoch nicht gesperrt.

Answer (score 6):

Auf der [Website von Fritz Jörn](http://www.joern.de/tipsn78.htm#st) ist folgende plausible Begründung zu finden:

> st :: durfte früher nicht getrennt werden, nicht weils eine Fraktur-Ligatur war, sondern weil es in der deutschen Handschrift (Kurrentschrift) stets als Buchstabenverbindung geschrieben wurde, wie Hermann Möcker, Wien, herausfand.

Die Website fand ich über den Thread [Zwangsverbünde im gesperrten Fraktursatz: Das ſt](http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/23604-zwangsverb%C3%BCnde-im-gesperrten-fraktursatz-das-t/) auf typografie.info. Dort werden auch mehrere Belege dafür angeführt, dass ſt nicht immer einheitlich als Zwangsligatur gesetzt wurde.

Comment: Das ist in der Tat die plausibelste Begründung, die ich bisher gehört habe, danke. Jetzt fehlt nur noch irgendeine historische Quelle hierzu. (Den Thread of Typografie.info kannte ich auch noch nicht (und das obwohl ich dort Moderator für gebrochene Schriften bin), was vermutlich damit zusammenhängt, dass er bei einer Softwareumstellung zerschossen wurde.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich vermute in einer Veröffentlichung von Möcker wird etwas dazu stehen. Dazu konnte ich online jedoch nichts finden.

Comment: Ich bin der Ansicht, dass man da noch ein bißchen tiefer graben müsste: *Warum ist/durfte "st" eine Ligatur geworden?* Ausschliesslich ästhetisch Gründe sehe ich da nicht, sondern eher Aussprachegründe.

Answer (score 0):

Aus Kosten- und Platzgründen standen bis in die Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts in der gebräuchlichen Frakturschrift das "s" als langes "s" und das "t" auf einem gemeinsamen Druckblock. Das Trennverbot wurde deswegen höchstwahrscheinlich beibehalten, um die alten Druckblöcke nicht wegwerfen zu müssen. [(hier gefunden)](http://www.fr-online.de/rechtschreibreform/rechtschreibung---teil-5--st--tut-nix-mehr-weh,1473252,2715958.html)

Der Verdacht wird fast schon zur Gewissheit, nimmt man noch diese [Anmerkung zur II. Orthographische Konferenz hinzu](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901#Beschl.C3.BCsse): *"... st (in den Fällen, in denen nach den Regeln des Fraktursatzes ein langes s gesetzt wird) jedoch nie getrennt werden dürfen ..."*

Comment: Das mit dem gemeinsamen Druckblock nannte man auch *Ligatur* (s. o.) und das galt auch für *tz* und *ck.* Selbst abgesehen davon ist das Argument schwach, da nur eine sehr geringer Anteil aller *ſt* eine Silbentrennung erfahren hätte und man die alten Ligaturen mit Nichten hätte wegschmeißen müssen.

Comment: Das erklärt auch nicht, wieso diese Regel für die Schreibschrift gilt.

Comment: fast zwei Drittel der Druckerzeugnisse wurden früher in Fraktur gedruckt

Comment: @user unknown: Dass eine Regel vom Gedruckten aufs Geschriebene überschlägt oder umgekehrt, ist wenig verwunderlich. Mir geht es aber vor allem darum, wie es dazu kommen konnte, dass diese Regel *ſt* betrifft, aber nicht *tz* oder *ck.*

Comment: Wieso ist das wenig verwunderlich? Da kaum ein Lehrer Drucker ist wird dieser kaum aus Gewohnheit so eine Regel zitieren. Wer den Grund der Regel kennt sollte sie auch nicht auf Geschriebenes übertragen. Wieso ist das wenig verwunderlich?

Comment: @user unknown: Es gibt noch andere Wege, sich Rechtschreibung anzueignen, als Lehrer, z. B. die Lektüre von gedrucktem Material – zumal diese Regeln teilweise aus der Zeit vor einer einheitlichen Rechtschreibung stammen. Warum nutzen denn reale Menschen das Deppenapostroph? Wohl kaum, weil sie es in der Schule so gelernt haben, sich der Rechtschreibregelausnahme bewusst sind oder aus Überzeugung. (Hmm, ich habe gerade im ersten Satz ein nettes Beispiel für Kommasetzung produziert.)

Comment: Der Spruch `Trenne nie st - denn es tut ihm weh` stammt aus gedruckten Werken? `Warum nutzen denn reale Menschen das Deppenapostroph?` Weil es dafür einen gedruckten Reim gibt? http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+denn+es+tut+ihm+weh&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=0&share=

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Der ist schmuck: *...man die alten Ligaturen mit Nichten hätte...* . Du bringst gleich die ganze Familie mit den Ligaturen um die Ecke.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht hat es damit zu tun, dass die Verbindung *st* – im Unterschied zu *tz, ck* usw. – in Endungen vorkommt, insbesondere im Superlativ der Adjektive:

- schnell – schnellste
- warm – wärmste
- lieb – liebste

Bei solchen Superlativen entspricht die Trennung *schnell-ste, wärm-ste, lieb-ste* der Wortgliederung.

Comment: Ein *fes-ter* Griff, der *fes-tes-te* Griff. Ich kann deinem Argument nicht ganz folgen. (Wenn das wirklich der Grund gewesen wäre, hätte das meines Erachtens nur für eine Regel »Trenne nie Superlativ-st« reichen dürfen, und das Wort könnte trotzdem *fes-te-ster* getrennt werden.)

Comment: Wohl hätte das gereicht, aber das wäre ja noch komplizierter: *Trenne nie Superlativ-st, denn das tut ihm weh, aber Wortstamm-st kennt keine Schmerzen.* Mein Argument ist eben, dass es um Analogie geht. Hätte ich wohl explizit hinschreiben müssen.