# What is the linguistic necessity for the letter 'ß' in German that can't be expressed with 'ss'?

Tags: standard-german, blackletter, consonant-sounds

For a long time Germany has been playing around with the letters '**ss**' which are sometimes, but not always, written as a separate letter **ß**. This letter has undergone some changes but even after modern reforms, hasn't been abandoned. Sometimes it's **ß**, sometimes **ss**, sometimes **ſs**, and sometimes **ſz** (long-S variants).

My question is, what's the real necessity for a distinct letter, as a purely linguistic matter, that can't be expressed with **ss** at all times? Is there some ambiguity or problem if it's not used at all? Or is it just the desire to preserve historic tradition? What would happen if it were completely dropped in favor of the simple **s-s?**

Note: I tagged this with "blackletter" since the letter comes from old scripts with the long-S.

Is it just a nod to some tradition, or an actual linguistic need?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ß was removed from Swiss-German alphabet some time ago and AFAIK they're doing fine. Just some more ambiguous words, where one has to get the meaning from context (Masse, Busse).

Comment: The letter *v* could also be replaced everywhere by *f* or *w*. But why should it?

Comment: Don't assume that phonemena in languages are generally based on "necessity". They have developed as they have, for various reasons and circumstances, but there is rarely a "necessity". - What necessity is there for the spelling of beard, weird, wear, tier, tear, beer, bear etc.  in English (and their respective pronunciations)?

Comment: @CarstenS Because there are people who believe that their personal idea of beauty is very, very important, and that the world should adapt to it. (Guess how we got the last orthographic reform.)

Comment: Related: [Why is »ß« substituted with »ss« rather than »sz«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/10444/2594)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the question isn't what the letter is substituted with, the question is why there's a need for it. It's an irrelevant "Related," sorry.

Comment: @geneb.: I am not saying it’s a duplicate. I am saying it’s related. At least some of the answers will in part answer your question.

Comment: Necessity!? You can obviously write everything as a sequence of zeroes and ones... for less extreme measures, of course you can do without ue, ae and oe, nd y cn vn d wtht vwls ltgthr, s rb wrtrs cn cnfrm. Bt s t prtt? s t smpl? You should have asked for function.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes that's what I meant. Don't worry, I love the letter ß as well as everything related to Fraktur and German ;) I was just wondering about the objective reason to have it in the alphabet.

Comment: What purpose does 'c' serve in English?  We already have 's' and 'k'

Comment: Sometimes using ß instead of ss can even change the whole meaning of a word. "Bier in Massen trinken" (drinking a lot of bier) is something different than "Bier in Maßen trinken" (drinking a responsible amount of beer).

Comment: The reason is *[ghoti](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti)*. :-)

Comment: **THAT** I can answer in ONE WORD: ***TRADITION***!!!!! :-)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can't call it a need, since Switzerland dropped *ß* at the beginning of the 20th century and has, apparently, not yet collapsed.

But *ß* does have a function. In intervocalic position, there is a triple opposition:

> Füße [fyːsə]
>   Küsse [kʏsə]
>   Düse [dyːzə]

Here, *ß* and *ss* both stand for voiceless [s], with *ß* signalling a preceding long vowel and *ss* a short vowel.

Both *ß* and *s* signal a long vowel, with *ß* standing for voiceless [s] and *s* for voiced [z].

---

1. A double consonant, such as *ss*, marking a short vowel is characteristic for the German spelling system.
2. Marking the distinction between [s] and [z] is unnecessary in other contexts: Initially, there is only <s>, pronounced [z]; and in final position, there is only [s], written as <s>, <ss> or <ß>, depending on what happens when a vowel is added: *Gras - Gräser* long vowel + [z], *Fuß - Füße* long vowel + [s], *Kuss - Küsse* short vowel + [s].
3. Note that the sound [z] cannot be represented by <z>, since the latter is used for [ts] initially or after a long vowel or diphthong: *Notiz(en)* [noˈtiːts], *Kreuz(e)* [kʁɔɪ̯ts].  After a short vowel, <tz> is used instead of <zz>: *Witz*.

---

Note that this triple opposition in intervocalic position has not been affected by the [1996 spelling reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996#Sounds_and_letters). Rather, the reform removed *ß* after short vowels at the end of a syllable (where all consonants are [devoiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing) and [z] cannot occur).

> Fuß [fuːs] *remained* Fuß
>   Kuß [kʊs] *became* Kuss

The effect is that now, at the end of a syllable, *ß* signifies a long vowel. This can be used to indicate pronunciation differences.

> Tschüß. [yː]
>   Tschüss. [ʏ]

<sup>Note that the offical post-reform spelling is *tschüs*. But my feeling is that people use the spelling with *ß* in order to indicate a long vowel.</sup>

In the old rules, *ß* in final position helped to make compounds more readable.

> Schlußsatz *instead of* Schlusssatz

One caveat: Saying that *ß* has the function of marking a preceding vowel as long does not imply that German strictly requires vowel length to be marked. For instance:

> nach [a:] - Dach [a]
>   Nische [i:] - Frische [ɪ]

Comment: "You can't call it a need, since Switzerland dropped ß at the beginning of the 20th century and has, apparently, not yet collapsed." - not sure this conclusion is so simple. It's well possible that the standard German pronunciation from Germany needs to distinguish some different sounds where the standard German pronunciation from Switzerland uses the same sound, anyway.

Comment: And with that said, discussing whether something is "necessary" is somewhat pointless without specifying *for what*. For making words identifiable? tatso konen fir noc mer pocstapen einsparen ;) It's all a question of what spelling you're used to, the rest is up to context-specific pronuncation rules. For having an unambiguous mapping between writing and pronunciation? For that purpose, on the other hand, *ß* is indeed necessary (albeit not without alternative solutions).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I was under the impression that the elimination of *ß* in Switzerland had typographic reasons. As to your second point, I deliberately avoided *need* and talked about *function* instead.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You're right to be cautious, but the pronounciation rules for standard German do not vary between Switzerland and Germany. In practice, the variation is just by local dialect (in both countries). ß is essentially a typographic accident that survived various spelling reforms in Germany, while it fell out of use in Switzerland because the typewriter keys were more urgently needed for French accented letters.

Comment: I'd have upvoted for the first sentence alone.

Comment: German has no long vowels, it's a completely different tone. I can stretch *küüü...ssen* all I want, still doesn't make it sound like *füüü...ße*.

Comment: Also be aware, that in names, especially in surnames (which tend to change seldom), the rule of long and short vowels before ss and ß does not necessary apply. I should know, since I have a ß in my surname, while the preceding vowel is short.

Comment: @vectory That’s correct for almost all vowels; *a* and *ä* being the exceptions.

Comment: Point to note @ David: In Bavarian and probably other southern dialects, a voiced /z/ essentially does not exist and /s/ is used in all places.

Comment: @Jan Even intervocalically? I was under the assumption that there was a *fortis* – *lenis* contrast. Do Bavarian schoolchildren have trouble distinguishing *ß* and *s* when they learn how to write? Growing up in Swabia, I can't recall any such difficulty, which leads me to believe that the dialect speakers surrounding me must have made some kind of distinction between the two sounds (even though voiced [z] is of course missing from Swabian as well).

Comment: @vectory: I don't understand. The "ü" in "küssen" and "Füße" seem like the exact same sound to me. The only expections where the pronunciation actually changes between long and short appear to be "e" and "o".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper *e* and *o* are the most obvious because pronunciation changes from open to closed or vice-versa. The same is true for *ö*. *i/u/ü* are also more open and more centralised when short but the quality difference is less pronounced. Long *ä* and long *a* are the only ones whose quality is exactly like the short vowel. (Regional variations may exist.)

Comment: @DavidVogt yes, most of the time. However, most of the intervocalic *s* end up being terminal as they are followed by shwa-e in standard pronunciation which is lost in Bavarian (e.g. *Hase, Rose*)

Answer (score 21):

Your reference to  ſz is somewhat misleading, since this is more a typographical aspect, how ß is represented, in the age of Unicode surely not a problem.

From purely practical point of view, ß is a sort of convenience, like the uppercase of substantives. In reformed orthography it helps for pronounciation, and in general assists disambiguation:

> Masse (spoken [ˈmasə]] <-> Maße (spoken [ˈmaːsə])

are completely different words (unfortunately both related to physical properties of an object), and using the same representation requires more context for decision, what is actually meant.

Comment: As a practical example, without the ß it would be impossible to decide the meaning of "Alkohol in Massen trinken".

Comment: @firefrorefiddle do you decide the meaning of that when it's spoken? I'd expect this to be a source of puns.

Comment: @SassaNF No, you pronounce either the long or the short vowel, even in Switzerland. If written in the non-Swiss standard, the two pronunciations are distinct in spelling. If written in the Swiss standard, the spellings collapse like in *close* (almost) and *close* (a door) but the pronunciation is distinct.

Comment: @firefrorefiddle but of course, it's vain to think that this would save us of ambiguity. Depending on the Region, either “Alkohol in Maßen trinken” or “Alkohol in Massen trinken” could also mean “Alkohol aus Maßkrügen trinken”.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think **ß** is *necessary* as such, at least in the sense that the German language would be more difficult to read or write without it, but it is "traditional". It is called "eszett" - literally "sz" - and in Fraktur it looks like it is clearly a ligature of of those two letters. I know too little about German etymology, but it is tempting to think that this reflects an older spelling - like *grosz* etc.